# Compile error when creating object within linkedlist within pointer array: C++

Tags: c++, templates, hash, linked-list, hashtable

***UPDATE****

so to start I am trying to attempt hashing. to try to make it short, I created a linkedlsit class which takes in a generic parameter . I have a hashtable class where I attempted to create (i believe) a array of linkedlist pointers (keeping in mind the linkedlist takes a generic type )

so, in my hashtable class, I have a private variable such that

```
SLL< Entry <string, int> >** list;
```

where SLL is my linked list, Entry is the object that holds a key (string) and value (int) and tying to make it a array of pointers.

in the hashtable constructor i create it like this

```
list = new SLL<Entry<string, int> > * [this->size];
```

now in my code, i attempt to append the Entry object into the array after my hashcode function ends

```
list[hash]->append(new Entry<string, int>(key, e));
```

however it get this error

```
HashTable.h: In member function 'void HashTable::createEntry(std::string, int)':
HashTable.h:78:53: error: no matching function for call to 'SLL<Entry<std::basic_string<char>, int> >::append(Entry<std::basic_string<char>, int>*)'
list[hash]->append(new Entry<string, int>(key, i));
```

it works if i replace Entry as the object within the linkedlist as jsut an int, or float, or even string

so what can be causing this? please and thank you, if you need any more info, let me know :)

```
#ifndef SLL_H
#define SLL_H

 template <class T>
class SLL 
{
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    int size;

public:
    SLL();
    virtual ~SLL();
    void append(T&);
    void append(T*);
    void prepend(T);
    void deleteElem(int);
    void toString();
    int getSize();
    void insertAt(T, int);
    T retrieveDataAt(int);
 };
 #endif /* SLL_H */

 template <class T>
SLL<T>::SLL() 
 {
this->tail = NULL;
this->head = NULL;
this->size = 0;
}
void SLL<T>::append(T data)
{
//do stuff
        this->head = new Node<T>(data);;
 }
```

Comment: Does `SLL<T>` have a member function that looks like `append(T*)`? I think you need to try to narrow down the code involved in this (and update your question), otherwise there's very little to go on.

Comment: updated with the SLL class excluding a few functions, so I do not have a append(T*) im guess, the class (objects) need to be passed as a pointer thus the T* part?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with the code you posted, and it just goes to show
that when using templates you need to be sure everything matches up nicely.
Especially because the compiler will not even care about some types of errors
until you actually instantiate a template with a certain type.

The first is that your class `SLL<T>` *declares* a number of member functions,
two of which are `SLL::append(T&)` and `SLL::append(T*)`. The problem is that in
the example code you posted, the member function you are *defining* is
`SLL::append(T)`, which doesn't exist!

The second is that because `new` returns a pointer to a type, your code:

```
list[hash]->append(new Entry<string, int>(key, e));
```

is equivalent to

```
Entry<string, int>* data_ptr = new Entry<string, int>(key, e);
list[hash]->append(data_ptr);
```

which will look for a member function of the form `SLL::append(T*)` not
`SLL::append(T)`, and no such function has been defined!

Here's some minimally working code that should compile for you. Note that I
used `std::pair` instead of `Entry` for brevity and that you'll need to compile with a
`-std=c++11` or equivalent flag (e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`) since I used `nullptr`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class SLL;

// singly linked list node
template<class T>
class Node
{
private:
    Node<T> *next;
    T data;

    friend class SLL<T>;
public:
    Node(T input) : next(nullptr),
        data(input) {}
    ~Node() {delete next;}
};

// the singly linked list class
template <class T>
class SLL
{
private:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* tail;
    std::size_t size;

public:
    SLL() : head(nullptr),
        tail(nullptr), size(0) {}
    ~SLL() {delete head;}

    std::size_t getSize() const {
        return size;}
    void append(T data);
};

template<class T>
void SLL<T>::append(T data)
{
    Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(data);
    if (!head)
        head = temp;

    if (tail)
        tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;

    size += 1;
}

int main()
{
    // less typing
    using list_type = SLL<std::pair<std::string, int>>;

    // allocation for the list of lists
    std::size_t hash_size = 10;
    list_type** list_of_lists = new list_type*[hash_size]();

    // data to input
    std::string key = "key";
    int value = 9330323;

    std::size_t hash = 4;

    // check and append
    if (!list_of_lists[hash])
        list_of_lists[hash] = new list_type;

    list_of_lists[hash]->append(std::pair<std::string, int>(key, value));

    // cleanup
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < hash_size; ++i)
        delete list_of_lists[i];
    delete[] list_of_lists;
}
```

Comment: before posted here i tried 

     `Entry<string, int> temp("test", 0);`

     `list[hash]->append(temp);`

and gave me same error, but i can try again when i get on my pc

Comment: @TannerSummers I've updated my answer, including some example code.